# lightning-input reportValidity does not fire on button click

Tags: validation, lightninginput

I have these lightning-input components. The error does not show when the user leaves it empty and clicks on Next button. Also I have two input components here, is there a way I could check the validity for both together and fire error messages appropriately?

Here is the HTML part -

```
<lightning-input class="heightInputCmp"
                                data-name="heightInput" type="text" label="Enter Height"
                                required></lightning-input>
<lightning-input class="weightInputCmp" data-name="weightInput" type="text"
                                label="Enter Weight" required></lightning-input>
<lightning-button variant="brand" label="Next" onclick={handleNextClick}
                class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
```

Here is the JS.

```
handleNextClick() {

        var heightInput = this.template.querySelector("heightInputCmp");
        var heightInputComponent = heightInput.value;
        if (!heightInputComponent) {
            heightInput.setCustomValidity('This field cannot be empty.')
        } else {
            heightInput.setCustomValidity('')
        }
        heightInput.reportValidity();
}
```

Comment: If you are using class name as a selector you will need a dot character prefixed to the class name.

Comment: @manubkk even with the dot char it is not working

Comment: @sumchans where is this component used? Adding your code to a basic component just on a page (and updating the selector to .heightInputCmp as noted) renders the custom error as expected. Also, if you wish to check the validity of both inputs, you just need to duplicate what you have done so far but with the second input.